# JavaScript geocoder

Tags: javascript, performance, jquery, formatting, geospatial

I'm pretty excited to have coded my first JavaScript file which now works, and I've spent my evening trying to improve it.

It takes a location in the `#loc` input box and geocodes it (gets coordinates from a location) when the search button is pressed, or when the autosuggestion is clicked, then submits the form.

I've worked hard on this but I am really interested to see if any JavaScript gurus can spot any mistakes, because I love beautiful code.

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/E8sNt/)

```
var coded = false;
geocode();
$.cookie("country", "uk");

// GEOCODE FUNCTION
function geocode() {
        var input = $('#loc')[0];
        var options = {types: ['geocode']};
        var country_code = $.cookie('country');

        if (country_code) {
                options.componentRestrictions = {
                        'country': country_code
                };
        }

        var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input, options);

        google.maps.event.addListener(autocomplete, 'place_changed', function() {
                processLocation();
        });

        $('#searchform').on('submit', function(e) {
                if (coded === false) {
                        processLocation();
                }
                return true;
        });

        $("#loc").bind("change paste keyup", function() {
                coded = false;
        });
}

function processLocation() {
        var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
        var address = $('#loc').val();
        geocoder.geocode({
                'address': address
        },
        function(results, status) {
                if (status === google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                        coded = true;
                        $('#lat').val(results[0].geometry.location.lat());
                        $('#lng').val(results[0].geometry.location.lng());
                } else {
                        coded = false;
                        alert("Sorry - We couldn't find this location. Please try an alternative");
                }
        });
        coded = true;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at your code, the first thing that stands out is the `coded` variable. You're checking or setting its value in many different places, which is the sort of thing you want to avoid, as it can quickly lead to errors. You're manually keeping track of the state.

A simpler, more robust solution would be to store the last searched-for location in the `processLocation` function, and if it's asked twice or more for that same location, give the same result as the first time. That way, the logic is all in one place.

The second thing I notice is that there's some duplication going on. For instance, getting `$("#loc")` several times, and in different functions. Another thing you'll want to avoid. It's the DRY principle: Don't repeat yourself.

Lastly, I'm afraid there's an outright bug. You use `$.cookie` to set the country to "uk", and that'll happen every time the page loads. Cookies exist to store data *between* pageviews; by overwriting any existing value with "uk" every time the page loads, what you're doing is no different from just writing `var country = "uk";` and not using cookies at all. Moreover, unless there's a way for the user to choose another country, there's not even a reason to use a `var` much less a cookie. You could simply set `componentRestrictions.country` to "uk" directly.

Here's a rewrite

```
$(function () { // this will be called when the page has loaded - and keep things contained
  var input = $("#loc"), // find the elements once and for all
      lat   = $("#lat"),
      lng   = $("#lng"),
      lastQuery = null,
      autocomplete;

  function processLocation(query) {
    var query = $.trim(input.val()),
        geocoder;

    if( !query || query == lastQuery ) {
      return; // stop here if query is empty or the same as last time
    }

    lastQuery = query; // store for next time

    geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    geocoder.geocode({ address: query }, function(results, status) {
      if( status === google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK ) {
        lat.val(results[0].geometry.location.lat());
        lng.val(results[0].geometry.location.lng());
      } else {
        alert("Sorry - We couldn't find this location. Please try an alternative");
      }
    });
  }

  // set up

  autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input[0], {
    types: ["geocode"],
    componentRestrictions: {
      country: "uk"
    }
  });

  google.maps.event.addListener(autocomplete, 'place_changed', processLocation);

  $('#searchform').on('submit', function (event) {
    processLocation();
    event.preventDefault();
  });
});
```

Comment: Flambino, thank you so much, this is a really clean rewrite. I've been playing with this all morning but there is one little problem with it that I can't fix. After the search button is clicked it should geocode (if it hasn't already) and then submit the form. Your code does everything right except submit the form, can you tell me how I do that?

Comment: @JamesWillson Ah - missed that, sorry. I'd recommend that you should post the question on StackOverflow (since it's a "how do I..."-question) - or maybe there's something similar there already. I'd answer here, but the structure/flow of things will need some tweaking (you have to wait for the geocoding to succeed/fail before the form submission can procede. Otherwise, the form might well get submitted before the geocoder gets results back). Your code didn't make such checks, so neither does mine, and I'd rather keep my answer as close to 1:1 with the original question. I hope that makes sense